# Slow multiprocessing when using torch

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pytorch

I have a function `func` that takes on average 9 sec to run. But when I try to use multiprocessing to parallelize it (even using torch.multiprocessing) each inference takes on average 20 sec why is that ?

`func` is an inference function which takes in a `patient_name` and runs a torch model in inference on that patient's data.

```
device = torch.device(torch.device('cpu'))

def func(patient_name):
    
    data = np.load(my_dict[system_name]['data_path'])
    model_state = torch.load(my_dict[system_name]['model_state_path'],map_location='cpu')
    
    model = my_net(my_dict[system_name]['HPs'])
    model = model.to(device)

    model.load_state_dict(model_state)
    model.eval()
    
    result = model(torch.FloatTensor(data).to(device))
    return result

from torch.multiprocessing import pool

core_cnt = 10

pool = Pool(core_cnt)
out = pool.starmap(func, pool_args)
```

Comment: I answered with suggestions but it would be nice if could show how did you use `multiprocessing` and `torch.multiprocessing`. I will update my answer when you do that, if applicable

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the inference on your model architecture with data that you provide already uses substantial computational power. That would make OS process scheduler to switch between each process which takes additional time.

Also, you load model every time inside your function. It is always faster to copy data object between processes than read it from a disk (that's the strategy with `multiprocessing`, or share model altogether with `torch.multiprocessing`)

Comment: I added the way i run the multiprocessing to my question. 
I test this function to run multiprocessing without a pytorch included and it runs fine with the data loading etc. the time it takes per run is the same. It only slows down when I am actually running this `model(torch.FloatTensor(data).to(device))`
Note, this is a particular case where I build a model per patient. This choice is more relevant to the problem, so the models are different here.